# Why would the union of an empty set with another set results in an empty set in python?

Tags: python

```
a = set()
b = set([1,2])
print a.union(b)
```

The result is an empty set. But if a is not an empty set, the result is correct.

Comment: your code show set([1,2]) as the result of the print statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! The result of the union between the set `empty` and b is always `b`.

```
a = set()
b = set([1,2])
print a.union(b) #return {1, 2}
```

The intersection between an `empty` set and anything is the set `empty`.

```
print a.intersection(b) #return set()
```